# Clarification: For Jenkins fastlane setup for ios shall i need xcode in my machine

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, fastlane, iosdeployment

Clarification: For Jenkins fastlane setup for ios shall i need xcode in my machine

I need to know shall i need Xcode in my machine to setup jenkins + fastlane for my ios app

In this doc steps, I not see it was essential to use xcode for jenkins setup
https://medium.com/@priya_talreja/ci-cd-in-ios-using-jenkins-and-fastlane-7b0f9218de8f

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need the xcode because fastlane and jenkins use command-line tools for xcode for build, archive and etc.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/

Comment: Which cloud platform is preferrable for this? AWS or AZURE or GCP